# Stop after display linked list c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I run my program, when it run finish `display(head)`, it will stop and won't execute last line `cout << "Done";`

Anybody coude help me to fix this problem :D

This my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct Node{
    Node* next;
    char* data;
};

void initNode(struct Node *head, char *n){
    head->data = n;
    head->next = NULL;
}

void addNode(struct Node *head, char *n){
    Node *newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = n;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    Node *cur = head;
    while(cur){
        if(cur->next == NULL){
            cur->next = newNode;
            return;
        }
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}

void display(struct Node *head){
    Node *list = head;
    while(list != NULL){
        cout << list->data <<endl;
        list = list->next;
    }
}

int main(){
    struct Node *head = new Node;
    char str[] = "-  This is a sample string";
    char * pch;

    pch = strtok (str," ");
    initNode(head, pch);
    while (pch != NULL){
        pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
        addNode(head, pch);
  }

  display(head);
  cout << "Done";
}
```

Comment: If you check your logic carefully, you'll realise your final node has `NULL` in the `data` field - your `cout << list->data` then dereferences `NULL` in an attempt to find text, and crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As TonyD pointed the last call to strtok() gives you NULL pch and you try to add it as last element to your linked list.
This is simple fix would make your code run:

```
while (pch != NULL)
{
    pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
    if(pch!=NULL) // do not add empty data to your linked list
    {
        addNode(head, pch);
    }
}
```